# Calculate p-value for main effect in 2x2 design

Tags: anova, t-test, p-value

How can I obtain a p-value for a main effect in a 2x2 design?

I have 12 participants and 2 independent condition categories which I represent by *letter*, and *case*. That means my conditions are **A**, **a**, **B**, **b**.

All 12 participants take part in:

```
       Case
Letter A  a
       B  b
```

Thus, my data could be:

```
   participant  measurement letter   case
0        ET001     1.785561      a  lower
1        ET002     1.202052      a  lower
2        ET003     0.996961      a  lower
3        ET004     1.144598      a  lower
4        ET005     1.143536      a  lower
5        ET006     1.219683      a  lower
6        ET007     1.038158      a  lower
7        ET008     1.042968      a  lower
8        ET009     1.339907      a  lower
9        ET010     1.034547      a  lower
10       ET011     1.073431      a  lower
11       ET012     1.247102      a  lower
12       ET001     1.637633      a  upper
13       ET002     1.124755      a  upper
14       ET003     0.978225      a  upper
15       ET004     1.098280      a  upper
16       ET005     1.134780      a  upper
17       ET006     1.197491      a  upper
18       ET007     1.059350      a  upper
19       ET008     1.060859      a  upper
20       ET009     1.146489      a  upper
21       ET010     1.040131      a  upper
22       ET011     1.071372      a  upper
23       ET012     1.279824      a  upper
24       ET001     1.936211      b  lower
25       ET002     1.231004      b  lower
26       ET003     1.017406      b  lower
27       ET004     1.166573      b  lower
28       ET005     1.099156      b  lower
29       ET006     1.212767      b  lower
30       ET007     1.024333      b  lower
31       ET008     1.014315      b  lower
32       ET009     1.448073      b  lower
33       ET010     1.096295      b  lower
34       ET011     1.069086      b  lower
35       ET012     1.181156      b  lower
36       ET001     1.965226      b  upper
37       ET002     1.110897      b  upper
38       ET003     0.997396      b  upper
39       ET004     1.141867      b  upper
40       ET005     1.162732      b  upper
41       ET006     1.239641      b  upper
42       ET007     1.075972      b  upper
43       ET008     1.022703      b  upper
44       ET009     1.303017      b  upper
45       ET010     1.057868      b  upper
46       ET011     1.095592      b  upper
47       ET012     1.219926      b  upper
```

I would like to get a p-value for the effect of *letter*. Meaning I will want to compare categories **A,a** with categories **B,b**.

What test should I use for this?
My ideas:

- Related sample t-test for **A** concatenated with **a** vs. **B** concatenated with **b** (24 vs. 24 values)
- Related sample t-test *p* of **A** vs. **B** multiplied by related sample t-test *p* of **a** vs. **b**

What would be the correct way? And if my propositions are flawed - why? (at least one of them is, as they give me similar but not identical values)

Comment: Your description is somewhat confusing. Can you provide a 2 by 2 table illustration of your data? Are all 10 subjects each experiencing A, a, B and b. Or are 10 subjects experiencing A, a different 10 subjects experiencing a, a different 10 subjects experiencing B, etc.?

Comment: @Alexis All participants take part in all 4 conditions, I updated my description to make it clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided a table of your data. You have merely provided a table of variable values.

Comment: @Alexis Yes, and that table is sampled for 12 participants. In case that is still unclear, I have just added some data to illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually an example where you would want to use either a [repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design), or a nonparametric analog to repeated measures ANOVA, such as the [Friedman Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test).

Is my attempt to reconsider your data structure below correct?

```
Subject A       a      B      b
Subj1   Obs1A   Obs1a  Obs1B  Obs1b
Subj2   Obs2A   Obs2a  Obs2B  Obs2b
...     ...     ...    ...    ... 
Subj10  Obs10A  Obs10a Obs10B Obs10b
```

Another way of representing data from a repeated measures design:

```
Subject Condition Observation
Subj1   A         Obs1A
Subj1   a         Obs1a
Subj1   B         Obs2B
Subj1   b         Obs2b
.       .         .
.       .         .
.       .         .
Subj10  A         Obs10A
Subj10  a         Obs10a
Subj10  B         Obs10B
Subj10  b         Obs10b
```

If so, and if your observations on A,a,B, and b meet the repeated measures ANOVA assumptions (sphericity, normality, i.i.d.), then repeated measure ANOVA is the way to go.

Otherwise you can use a nonparametric analog of repeated measures ANOVA like Friedman's test.

Comment: why do you numerate all observations by one participant with the same number? there are 4 different observations per participant. Does that change anything? Also, why would the t-test be amiss?

Comment: It depends on the data structure. Whet I presented (based on your question) was my hazarded guess at the data structure which sounded to me like it was a repeated measures design. Why not a *t* test? Well for starters because there are 4, not two groups.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to run a paired difference test on group A vs. B (and also a vs. b)? I suggest this simply because it appears that @TheChymera is interested only in one or two pairwise differences with respect to the greater ANOVA (which gives p for *any* group not equal to other groups, which includes differences that may not be of interest).

Comment: Well sure... though that would be *t* test**s**, and it is not clear to me *which* specific pairwise comparisons TheChymera is interested in. Of course that also raises multiple comparisons issues.

Comment: @Matt yes, that is precisely what I meant. I want to test whether or not the *letter* parameter has an effect independent from the *case* parameter. Normally this would be a related sample t-test. My confusion stems from the fact that concatenating A and a and B and b and running a related sample t-test would imply that I have 2 related measurements for 20 participants - but I only have 10 participants.

Comment: @Alexis also, why do you say ANOVA and not MANOVA? as far as I understand, using an ANOVA would be appropriate for a 4x1 condition design (4 independent conditions) but I have a 2x2 design.

Comment: But I do not see a 2x2 design. I see a repeated measures design because each subject is measured under each of the four conditions (AaBb) once. That is the definition of a repeated measures (blocked) design. I am also confused why you assert independence, when each subject is being measured four times. Again: repeated measures ANOVA. What is your objection to repeated measures?

Comment: @Alexis I do not assert independence, it's just that I have 2 independent variables (case and letter) not 4. A simple repeated measures ANOVA gives me a single p value with the assumption that the 4 categories are independent. That makes no sense given my design. Perhaps you would like to tell me exactly what I do not explain correctly regarding my design? I believe this is the simplest example of a within subjects 2x2 design

Comment: @Alexis Yes, I am aware that the measurements are dependent between subjects. Please refer to my original post for a data example.